# How do I map array of objects to an existing array on MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Please how can I make this work on mongoDB.
For each item in an array, fetch data which contains the item from another collection.

For example:

> "users" : [{
> "name": "John doe",
> "age": 51
> },
> {
> "name": "Jake kim",
> "age": 50
> },
> {
> "name": "Jim son",
> "age": 51
> }]

On another collection I have

> "age": [50,51,52,53,54]

Now my desire result is

> "50" : [{
> "name": "Jake kim",
> "age": 50
> }],
> "51" : [{
> "name": "John doe",
> "age": 51
> },
> {
> "name": "Jim son",
> "age": 51
> }]

Comment: is "users" a collection or a nested field? it's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. Get the array of users.

```
const users = [{ "name": "John doe", "age": 51 }, { "name": "Jake kim", "age": 50 }, { "name": "Jim son", "age": 51 }]
```

Get the array of ages

```
const age = [50,51,52,53,54]
```

Then you can map through the array of ages, returning an object that has the user that has the same age, here is the algorithm.

```
const mapped = age.map(age => {
  const user = {}
  user[age] = users.find(ob => ob.age === age);
  return user;
})
```

If you print out the mapped result. This is what it will look like, For the ages that we couldn't find their users, they just have an undefined value.

```
    console.log(mapped)
    [
      { '50': { name: 'Jake kim', age: 50 } },
      { '51': { name: 'John doe', age: 51 } },
      { '52': undefined },
      { '53': undefined },
      { '54': undefined }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll need the `age` data in your case. However I've provided the both versions which one use the age list but other does not. Please find them below.

```js
const users = [{ "name": "John doe", "age": 51 }, { "name": "Jake kim", "age": 50 }, { "name": "Jim son", "age": 51 }];
const age = [50, 51, 52, 53, 54];

const desired = users.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  (prev[cur.age] ?? (prev[cur.age] = [])).push(cur); 
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log("This is the expected result", desired); 

const desired2 = users.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  (prev[cur.age] ?? (prev[cur.age] = [])).push(cur); 
  return prev;
}, age.reduce((prev, cur) => {
  prev[cur] = [];
  return prev;
}, {}));

console.log("This is the expected result with empty ages", desired2);
```